# make all values of mutiple columns in one column Power Bi

Tags: powerbi

I want to get this result (in the picture) using this code but it doesn't work , any suggestions to have all the  values of all columns in one column and keep occurrences.

[image]

```
AllZipCode=UNION(SUMMARIZE('Table','Table'[ZipCode1]),
SUMMARIZE('Table','Table'[ZipCode2]),
SUMMARIZE('Table','Table'[ZipCode3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely to combine all the column and return it in the existing table, else it will return error, by create a new table to join all the column referring to the table, you can achieve the expected output:

```
Table = UNION(SELECTCOLUMNS(Sheet1,"col1",Sheet1[Zip1]),
            SELECTCOLUMNS(Sheet1,"col2",Sheet1[Zip2]),
                SELECTCOLUMNS(Sheet1,"col3",Sheet1[Zip3]))
```

**Original table :**

[image]

**Union table:**

[image]